# Does os module work inside ProcessPoolExecutor function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

When I run `convert(mp3_files[5])` it creates `wav` file as expected. When I do the same with `ProcessPoolExecutor` I see `'os' is not defined` exception. What is wrong?

```
import concurrent.futures, subprocess, multiprocessing

def convert(mp3_file):
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(mp3_file))[0]
    out = os.path.join(audio, file_name + '.wav')
    subprocess.run([exe_mpg123, '-q', '-e', 'f32', '-w', out, mp3_file])

def main():
    # convert(mp3_files[5])
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(convert, mp3_files)

        for result in results:
            print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    main()

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "C:\script.py", line 159, in <module>
#     main()
#   File "C:\script.py", line 108, in main
#     for result in results:
#   File "C:\Users\Asd\miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 483, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
#     for element in iterable:
#   File "C:\Users\Asd\miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
#     yield fs.pop().result()
#   File "C:\Users\Asd\miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 428, in result
#     return self.__get_result()
#   File "C:\Users\Asd\miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
#     raise self._exception
# NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

`os` was imported before. If I uncomment the line `convert(mp3_files[5])` it works.

I use Windows 10 64, Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)].

Comment: what happens if you comment out the "subprocess.run(" part?

Comment: The same error. I can put only one line inside the `convert` function `print(os.name)` and get `'os' is not defined` error.

Comment: I created a `mp3_files` list and an `audio` specification, removed the call to `subprocess.run` and returned `out` from function `convert` (right now the function returns `None` so the results you print aren't particularly interesting) and it ran successfully.

Comment: Strange. Can you try to use some other module (e.g. re) within convert, and see if you're getting an error?

Comment: Works for me. I commented out `subprocess.run` in `convert` and used a list of known filenames and returned `out`. - No Exception complaining about `os` module.

Comment: Since the actual issue seems not related to mp3 processing, can you please adjust your [mcve] to work without these parts? That would greatly simplify testing for people trying to help.

Comment: I'd like to mak it work on linux too, that's why I use `os.path`. `print(dir(re))` works.

Comment: There is something you are *not* showing that is causing the problem. Is your program much bigger than what you have shown (you haven't show, for example, the definitions of `mp3_files` and `audio`, so I know there is more)? Show us more, if you can.

Comment: @Booboo, in the traceback, the error occurs at line 159, so yeah, the OP is not showing everything. F. Vosnim, please try to create a [mre] and post the exact traceback corresponding to that code.

Comment: The code is very big. If I place everything nobody will read it.

Comment: That's why you should post a **minimal** reproducible example. And for other reasons too. Please read the link if you haven't done so yet. It will be probably be more helpful then any answer you'll find here, because you will also learn how to solve these issues by yourself.

Comment: I see you already created a mre, but posted it as an answer instead of updating the question...

Comment: @wovano you're right. Trying to write a minimal reproducible example I copied parts of my code and pasted them here in slightly different places. I thought if imports are made in global scope it does not matter where to place them. My mistake. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your comments, I found the issue. Using `ProcessPoolExecutor` on Windows you **MUST** place all imports you used inside `ProcessPoolExecutor` **BEFORE** `if __name__ == "__main__":`. This code works:

```
import os, concurrent.futures

def convert(mp3_file):
    print(os.name)

def main():
    mp3_files = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(convert, mp3_files)

        for result in results:
            print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This does not:

```
import concurrent.futures

def convert(mp3_file):
    print(os.name)

def main():
    mp3_files = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(convert, mp3_files)

        for result in results:
            print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    main()
```

When you run a simple function `convert(mp3_files[1])` it works always no matter where you placed your imports.